# Are there any circumstances in which 弈 (yì) could be mistaken for 野 (yě)?

Tags: topolect, mistakes

I understand the sounds and inflections are distinct, and that the only commonality is the initial consonant.  But what if it were a conversation between two speakers with different native dialects, where wine has been drunk, and the person speaking has a speech impediment, and the person mishearing is very old and hard of hearing. *(In other words, this question is about mistakes in communication and records as opposed to accuracy.)*

This is not a serious question, per se, but more of a fun question for literary purposes, playfully looking for a speculative (non-materialist) connection between the game of Yi, mentioned in the Zuo Zhuan and Analects, and the Battle of Muye.

Comment: I would say it is possible. But, always, it can be distinguished from the context.

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible if we say only one word, 奕 or 野, quickly and ambiguously.

When they are combined with other words, we have these words to judge it.

牧野 is the name of a place, and we always use this term as a whole.

奕 usually goes with 博 or 對 to form 博奕 or 對奕 for games.

Even somebody mixes 奕 with 野. It is not so easy to mix 博奕 (Bó yì) or 對奕 (Duì yì) with 牧野 (Mù yě).

Answer (score 1):

To me, these two words are very distinctive and I had never encountered a case for these two words which confused my understanding. I just can't think of any occasion off the top of my head.